# Does Concurrent substructures needs to be Concurrent?

Tags: c#, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency

In a multithreaded application I have to implement a `ConcurrentDictionary<string,Queue<MyClass>>;`
Does the queue need to be a `ConcurrentQueue`? Is it necessary? I will dequeue the elements all in the same thread so I think not. Am I right?
Edit: I not mentioned that I enqueue in a different thread of where I'm enqueuing so I think the right structure will be 
`Dictionary<string,ConcurrentQueue<MyClass>>`. The dictionary keys are edited only at startup

Comment: What about enqueuing ? Will there ever be more than 1 thread operating concurrently on the `Queue<MyClass>` that you place in the dictionary ?

Comment: Dictionary has to be concurrent only if there are concurrent modification and read operations. Is it true in your case?

Comment: In my case I have a single thread that populate the dictionary and enqueue new data into the sub-queue; then multiple threads that dequeue data, but only for the selected key.

Comment: mmmm probably I'm doing the opposite of what I should :) maybe is it better to use a Dictionary<string,ConcurrentQueue<MyClass>>? the dictionary key are modified only one time when the application start

Comment: @Andrew Cattaneo: Yes, it should be the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

If you only ever alter the queue in the `updateValueFactory` delegate passed to an `AddOrUpdate()` call to the concurrent dictionary, then you guarantee that the `Queue` object is only accessed by one thread at a time, so yes in that case you wouldn't need to use a `ConcurrentQueue`

For example, the following code would allow `Enqueue()` and `Dequeue()` to be called whenever you like by many different threads, and will prevent any individual `Queue` object in the `ConcurrentDictionary` from being accessed by more than one thread at a time:

```
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Queue<string>> dict;

    public static void Main()
    {
        dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Queue<string>>();
    }

    // If I do this on one thread...
    private static void Enqueue(string key, string value)
    {
        dict.AddOrUpdate(
            key,
            k => new Queue<string>(new[] { value }),
            (k, q) =>
                {
                    q.Enqueue(value);
                    return q;
                });
    }

    // And I do this on another thread...
    private static string Dequeue(string key)
    {
        string result = null;
        dict.AddOrUpdate(
            "key",
            k => new Queue<string>(),
            (k, q) =>
                {
                    result = q.Dequeue();
                    return q;
                });

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Using `AddOrUpdate` for de-queuing? That seems peculiar to me.